# Python can't find script in directory added to path [Cygwin]

Tags: python, cygwin

I'm trying to run a Python script from the command line, but I'm getting the error

```
$ python pscan2.py    
python: can't open file 'pscan2.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

However, I also have

```
$ which pscan2.py
/usr/bin/pscan2.py
```

and

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/MinGW64/bin:/cygdrive/c/Dwimperl/perl/bin:/cygdrive/c/Dwimperl/perl/site/bin:/cygdrive/c/Dwimperl/c/bin:/cygdrive/c/python27: C:/python25:/usr/lib/lapack:/usr/openwin/bin
```

I can import it within Python, since I've added the directory to the PYTHONPATH, and that works fine, but I have to specify the directory to get it to run at the command line, even though `which` can find it.

EDIT: emacs can't find it either...

Comment: Just 2 guesses: try to add `.py` to PATHEXT env variable. Try to do `chmod +x` on the script.

Comment: What command are you using to run the script?

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: sorry, it was python pscan2.py

Comment: @Riateche: sorry, I thought it worked, but neither one of those fixed the problem.

Comment: I don't think the Python interpreter searches for command-line scripts (which aren't `import`ed) using PYTHONPATH or anything else.

Comment: have you tried `pyscan2.py` on its own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to say python in the command line.  If you chmod +x it and it is in your path, You should be able to just call it like

$ pscan2.py

and it should work.  I don't know the specifics of cygwin but if you have the shebang line, it will automatically run it as a python script.

Comment: It does, thank you.  Do you know why emacs can't find it? It's not really a major issue for me, but I thought that having the directory in the PATH variable should be enough.

Comment: [Path Variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) The path environment variable defines a set of directories which executables can be located.  This doesn't necessarily specify locations to look at when finding files.